# ComboBox issue to display values correctly

Tags: c#, sql

This program uses fileds there is no data grid. what I am struggling with or you can say I want to correct functions to this is that.

If a user enters ID "1234" and this data already exists in the SQL Database instead of the program crashing or through exception, shows a pop up alert that the data already exists.

The filed Year is a combo box instead of a text box,  where we can see years like in a drop down list and if user chooses ID "1234" and chooses 2016 for this only the corresponding amount should appear in the amount text box, or if there are other years for this user ID can be selected and checked the amount.
The program is listing but not showing the year properly, my code is as follows :-

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbYear.Items.Clear();
        string sql = "";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            sql += "SELECT m.MemberId, m.Name, m.Address, m.Cellular, m.Email, p.PaymentId, p.Year, p.Amount from Members as m";
            sql += " INNER JOIN Payments as p ON m.MemberId = p.MemberId";
            sql += " WHERE m.MemberId = '" + tbID.Text + "' ORDER BY p.Year ASC";

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            if(dt.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<=dt.Rows.Count -1;i++)
                {
                    tbID.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MemberId"].ToString();
                    tbName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                    tbCellular.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Cellular"].ToString();
                    tbEmail.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString();
                    tbAddress.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();
                    tbAmount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString();
                    cmbYear.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Year"].ToString());
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    //This part displaying og the existing data from all the fileds
```

Comment: Its not clear with your description, what is your requirements here, if you want to insert data or just showing the data from DB, Also you are assigning values to the textboxes in loop it will overwrite all the values and will only shows the last value.

Comment: Is there any error you are getting while assigning year to the combobox, as the code looks fine. OR you are getting different values in the combobox.

Comment: Well Code works but let me try to explain! First when I call the personal data user Plus these two values "Year" & "Amount" the combo Box is empty ( its should display the first value, meaning that if the user has paid for 5 years, I should see 2016 in the combo Box and the Amount for that year "which appears")

Comment: The function I want is that when I choose the earlier year form the combo Box it should display corresponding value, which is not happening. After this works, do you think is it possible to edit and remove values for the attributes while the users personal data stands visable ?